# Cordova 6.3.1 android app javascript not firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been banging my head against the wall, if anyone could help, that would be super appreciated!

Both my js files are in www/js.  The cordova.js file was generated for me.

The "e" in body was just to make sure my new code was getting there.  It is, I've changed the letter in dozens of builds while trying to get this to work, just to make sure, and it always changes.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Ready Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="example.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    e
</body>
</html>
```

example.js

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

    // device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('yo');
    document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", onVolumeDown, false);
    // Add similar listeners for other events
}

function onVolumeDown() {
    alert('hey');
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;">asdfs</div>';

}
```

cordova.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

When I fire up the app, I get no alerts, and volume down does nothing.  This is what I get in the console when I build the apk

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.479 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        /root/hello/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
root@0SfCordova:~/hello# cordova -v
6.3.1
```

Also, I installed node and cordova on a blank ubuntu 14.04 digital ocean box using just the command line.  Where do I go to see console logs?  Thanks!  I have no idea how to debug in this environment.

Comment: did you happen to name your project 'cordova'? there should be a real 'cordova.js' file being loaded. your file is considered 'main.js', as it does not contain cordova js framework.

Comment: no, it's named hello, because I was following the hello world tutorial form their official docs.

Comment: @user2278120 are you testing it on android device?

Comment: Yes I am testing it on my android phone. I couldn't get an emulator to run through the command line oh 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Onload` event from html page.And don't write `cordova.js` file.Cordova will automatically create this file.You can use following code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Ready Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    e
</body>
</html>
```

example.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   alert('yo');
document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", onVolumeDown, false);
// Add similar listeners for other events
}
function onVolumeDown() {
   alert('hey');
}
```

Comment: Homen, thanks for trying, but I tried this and got no alerts as well.  Is it because I'm testing the apk file on an actual android device?

Comment: I written for actual android device only.I am sure it will work.Use only the above code.Nothing else.It will work

Comment: I did try exactly this. Not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you share the project's `www` folder in google drive or someting like that I can help you

Answer (score -1):

i came across the same error, it could not work on the emulator. Here is the solution that worked for me that i think will also work for you. I am running the latest cordova 6.3.1 on my MAC OS 10.12.

i removed this line of code from my html files. I am still trying to understand why it worked after removing the below line.

Comment: What line? Did you test OPs code to see if it fixes?

Comment: i see the line could not be posted. What i did was to remove the index.js that got came with the project inside js folder. I also removed the link to it from all my html pages. It seems it was the one that prevented my whole deviceready from firing. Why because after removing it from all my pages, deviceready could now fire even when running the app from a real device not emulator. You should try it and see.